# couldn't get value into javascript from a asp Label which value bind from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can't get value from getValue in JS and can't show value in showValue field.

Thanks in advance

ASPX PAGE CODE

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("<%=getValue.ClientID %>").innerHTML;    
document.getElementById('showValue').innerHTML = x;
</script>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="getValue" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="showValue" />
```

C# CODE

```
getValue.Text = "value from code";
```

Comment: Any errors? What happens?

Comment: no error. just can't get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call javascript once all the controls are rendered, then only you can get the proper id of the <asp:label> control, so you need to write that javascript code under window.onload().

Also for showValue, you need to use ClientID.

```
window.onload= function(){
   var x = document.getElementById("<%=getValue.ClientID%>").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById('<%=showValue.ClientID %>').innerHTML = x;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @w3hunter .. its working fine.

if i want to get JS variable x value from code behind, how can i do this ?

Comment: the value of x will be the text value of getValue control, so you should be able to access it using the Text property of getValue control, using "getValue.Text". Hope it answers your question. Btw, if you want to access javascript variable in CodeBehind, you can achieve it using hidden variables. You will get more info here http://forums.asp.net/p/1211504/2139016.aspx#2139016.